# Custom conversion of decimal value in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have to customize a specific column value of a query. where I have four types of cases  like

```
  empcode AbsentDays
  1       0.00
  6       0.50
  2       1.00
  3       1.50
  4       2.00
  5       2.50
```

and my expected output would be like

```
  1       0
  6       0.5
  2       1
  3       1.5
  4       2
  5       2.5
```

To do this I have tried this written below

```
AbsentDays = case 
                when AbsentDays = 0.00 
                   then convert(int, AbsentDays) 
                when AbsentDays >= 1.00 
                   then convert(decimal(10, 1), AbsentDays)
                -- when AbsentDays = 0.50 
                --    then 0.5
            end
```

But using this I can't get my desired result it is overriding other values.

Comment: For one column you can have one datatype only, ideally you should be doing it in UI or change the type to varchar

Comment: +1 on the UI to do it; but bad idea on the `varchar`. Storing decimals as a `varchar` is going to to be nothing but a pain in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A column can only have a single datatype. In order to see the different cases in the ways you describe, you'll have to use a `varchar`/`nvarchar` datatype:

```
AbsentDays = case 
                when AbsentDays = floor(AbsentDays)
                   then convert(nvarchar(max),convert(int, AbsentDays)) -- change to int if no decimal part
                else convert(nvarchar(max),convert(decimal(10, 1), AbsentDays)) -- else return one decimal
              end
```

Comment: I would upvote, but you use a character type and don't include the length.

Comment: And let's not ignore the confusing use of "text datatype" when "string datatype" would have been a better choice - because TEXT is a datatype.

Comment: Very observant, I am not used to it very much, thank you. I'll edit accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Don't cast as a float, you will lose in precision.

```
SELECT FORMAT(CAST(2.0 AS DECIMAL(9,6)), 'g15') -- will print 2
SELECT FORMAT(CAST(0.50 AS DECIMAL(9,6)), 'g15') -- will print 0.5
```

Comment: Note that format() is available from SQL Server 2012 onwards.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by casting it to `float` because the rightmost zeros after decimal point are trimmed in `float`:

```
select empcode, cast(AbsentDays as float)
from tbl
```

Comment: @ArnaudPeralta No it does not. What DBMS are you using? In SSMS it doesn't cast like that.

Comment: That was an exemple, but float are bad in general in database. You will find some examples easily.

Comment: @ArnaudPeralta Please provide a valid example when trying to disprove an answer. I just casted 0.5 to float and the result was 0.5

Comment: Try this : `SELECT FORMAT(CAST(15.12 AS FLOAT), 'g17')`. This is strange to justify the fact that a float is not precise ...

Comment: I didn't mention anything about the `format` function that you are using. Just try `SELECT CAST(15.12 AS FLOAT)` and see that this is not happening.

Comment: I use format for avoiding the rounding of sql server, with this we can see that the data is modified, and this not what op was asking. No one in database is using float value, there is a reason.

Comment: I just tried `SELECT CAST(5.1223423532530 AS FLOAT)` and nothing was rounded!

Comment: Because the rounding is on significant number.

Comment: Thank you for the discussion. It is wonderful to learn a new thing.